# Flex DropDownList Normal state border color

Tags: apache-flex

So I'm trying to change to appearance of a spark DropDownList when it's in the normal state. I thought I color used the borderColor property but that seems to only change the color of the border when the list is open. Any ideas? Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about `borderColor` in case of using standard `spark.skins.spark.DropDownListSkin`. But you can create your custom implementation of `spark.skins.spark.DropDownListButtonSkin` which displays button part of `DropDownList` and then create your own `DropDownListSkin` which will use your button with desired border. All the skins can be exact copies of original skins with minimum required customization.